# $Df(x_0)$ is one-to-one. show $f$ is one-to-one on a neighborhood of $x_0$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is $C^1$ and $Df(x_0)$ is one-to-one.

Show $f$ is one-to-one on a neighborhood of $x_0$.

I think it's about inverse function theorem. but i cannot prove it.

Comment: First of all, you need to have $m=n$. Write down exactly what the inverse function theorem states.

Comment: it may not be related with inverse function theorem. it's my guess.

Comment: Your guess was correct. And you must have $m=n$ or else the linear map $Df(x_0)\colon\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ could not possibly be invertible. I see somehow has edited to change that hypothesis. Could you please verify? Assuming $m>n$ and $Df(x_0)$ is one-to-one, the result is still true, but you have to dream up a new function $F\colon\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^{m-n}\to\Bbb R^m$ to which to apply the Inverse Function Theorem.

Comment: there isn't any condition about $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Isn't the fact that $Df(x_0)$ is 1-1 implies, $Df(x_0)$ is non-singular ? I mean after all, $Df(x_0)$ is a linear transformation; hence we can use the lemma 8.1 given in p64 in Munkres book, which directly states in this case that $f$ is one-to-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: By making a linear change of coordinates in $\Bbb R^m$, you may assume that
$$Df(x_0) = \begin{bmatrix} I \\ O \end{bmatrix}.$$
Now define $F\colon\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^{m-n}\to\Bbb R^m$ by $F(x,y) = f(x)+(0,y)$.

Comment: i proved when except $m<n$ with this method.
i think this method doesn't work when $m<n$.

Comment: When $m<n$, the linear map $Df(x_0)\colon\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ certainly cannot be one-to-one! By the way, this is why I ask questioners to tell us what they have done and what they're stuck on. You would have saved me a lot of time if you'd started with this!

Comment: oh................thank you